# Django/db-api broken for create database?

Tags: python, sql, django, sql-injection, python-db-api

Was hoping to use Django / db-api's built in string excaping, but it looks like it doesn't work for `create database` commands?

```
from django.db import connections
cursor = connections['dbadmin'].cursor()
cursor.execute('create database %s', ['foo'])
```

Which fails with

```
DatabaseError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''foo'' at line 1")
```

Although a straight, unparameterized `create database foo` works fine.

That looks like a bug to me, right?  `drop database` has a similar problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use parameters for metadata such as table or database names. This is a limitation of the underlying C library, not of DB-API.